# Manage redirected print queues from RD users on Server 2008 as Administrator

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, printing

How can I view the all the print queues on a 2008 server, even redirected ones created by remote desktop users?

When I log into a Server 2008 Server as Administrator, and I view the Printers folder (or use the Print Management tool) I only see my printers, and printers created via a 3rd party tool, Screwdrivers.  I don't see the redirected print queues created for remote desktop users.  Is there any way to see or manage these print queues as an administrator?

I can shadow the users and see their print queues, but that's the only way right now.

Comment: Why do you think you need to see them?  What do you think you can manage on them?  What is the real/root problem?

Comment: See change #2 here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/10/05/introducing-terminal-services-easy-print-part-3.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this is included in the Print Management mmc.

If you don't already have the Print Server role though, you'll need it first.

Then add yourself to the Print Operators group.  Log out of the administrative RDP session once and back in...then go into Print Management and "all printers".

(Oh and basically it is what joeqwerty linked to.)

Note: in case you didn't know already the (redirected 4) would correspond to the user with session ID 4 in Task Manager, since it isn't easily available within Print Management.

Comment: It was the Print Operators group membership that was required.